# Creating parent div inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have 25 items from JSON string. Each item comes with a key called "InRowPlcement" and the value is assigned as "0" or "1" or "2" so on.

```
{"ItemID":"516","ItemName":"Newzeland Lake Tysonno","InRowPlcement":0},
{"ItemID":"514","ItemName":"Newzeland Lake Tysonno","InRowPlcement":0},
{"ItemID":"546","ItemName":"Underworld Lives","InRowPlcement":0},
{"ItemID":"527","ItemName":"In a holiday beach","InRowPlcement":1},
{"ItemID":"542","ItemName":"Underworld Lives","InRowPlcement":1},
{"ItemID":"525","ItemName":"Lake somewhere","InRowPlcement":1},
{"ItemID":"540","ItemName":"Coral Structure at Andaman","InRowPlcement":1},
{"ItemID":"569","ItemName":"Ice Rock, Ireland","InRowPlcement":2}
```

The intention is, placed the "0" "InRowPlacement" items in the first row, "1" in the second row, "2" in the third row and so on. The number of items may vary in each row. It may possible from 1 to 5 in a single row.

I started the ng-repeat

```
<div class="ROW" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="COLUMN">{{item.ItemName}}<div>
</div>
```

I need the result should be like

```
    <div class="ROW">
        <div class="COLUMN">Newzeland Lake Tysonno<div>
        <div class="COLUMN">Newzeland Lake Tysonno<div>
        <div class="COLUMN">Underworld Lives<div>
    </div>
    <div class="ROW">
        <div class="COLUMN">In a holiday beach<div>
        <div class="COLUMN">Underworld Lives<div>
        <div class="COLUMN">Lake somewhere<div>
        <div class="COLUMN">Coral Structure at Andaman<div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

Based on the logic provided by @vp_arth, here is the actual code, which works for me

```
var view_rows = {};
angular.forEach(response.data, function(InRowPlcement,index){
    if (!view_rows[response.data[index].InRowPlcement]) view_rows[response.data[index].InRowPlcement] = [];
    view_rows[response.data[index].InRowPlcement].push(response.data[index]);

});
groups = view_rows;
```

Comment: Why just not change data structure for view layer? Iterate through and build what you need in your controller.

Comment: @vp_arth, Can you please give me some details, I just wanted to insert "</div><div class="ROW">" in a continuous repeat statement based on a key value which is available in the array. Just not able to fix the expression, how to check. using ng-if or something else.

Comment: inserting parts of DOM like this too smells. Just think angular. There is a data and there is directive (`ng-repeat`) to represent this data. You can write your own directive with custom behavior. You shouldn't manipulate with raw HTML parts (like `</div><div>`) - some kitten will die every time you try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with bunch of filters, but much better just prepare your data structure for view layer in the controller.

In your controller:

```
let data = [
{"ItemID":"516","ItemName":"Newzeland Lake Tysonno","InRowPlcement":0},
{"ItemID":"514","ItemName":"Newzeland Lake Tysonno","InRowPlcement":0},
{"ItemID":"546","ItemName":"Underworld Lives","InRowPlcement":0},
{"ItemID":"527","ItemName":"In a holiday beach","InRowPlcement":1},
{"ItemID":"542","ItemName":"Underworld Lives","InRowPlcement":1},
{"ItemID":"525","ItemName":"Lake somewhere","InRowPlcement":1},
{"ItemID":"540","ItemName":"Coral Structure at Andaman","InRowPlcement":1},
{"ItemID":"569","ItemName":"Ice Rock, Ireland","InRowPlcement":2}
];
let view_rows = {};
data.forEach(row => {
  if (!view_rows[row.InRowPlcment]) view_rows[row.InRowPlcment] = [];
  view_rows[row.InRowPlcment].push(row);
});
$scope.groups = view_rows;
```

Then, in view:

```
<div class="ROW" ng-repeat="(i, rows) in groups">
    <div class="COLUMN" ng-repeat="row in rows">{{row.ItemName}}<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @vp_arth, I got the desire result. I am going to update the actual controller code for the output in view.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the expression in DOM using `ng-if` to breakdown the items.

```
<div class="ROW" ng-repeat="item in items">
   <div ng-if ="item.InRowPlcement == 0">
     <div class="COLUMN">{{item.ItemName}}<div>
   </div>
   <div ng-if ="item.InRowPlcement == 1">
     <div class="COLUMN">{{item.ItemName}}<div>
   </div>
   <div ng-if ="item.InRowPlcement == 2">
     <div class="COLUMN">{{item.ItemName}}<div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/vFR6NUIu6Uyl8XSOTiax?p=preview

Comment: How can we to know, how much `InRowPlacement`s will be?

Comment: it says 25 items in the json , with each row has `InRowPlacements` value.

Comment: Thanks @Dev-One, it's a valid logic, but I don't want to add 25 ng-if in my view, someday the JSON node may increase.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the below code as per your requirement and believe that it would work as per your requirement.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
        <script>
            var mainModule = angular.module('mainModule', ['angular.filter']);
            mainModule.controller('mainCntrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.items = [
                    {"ItemID":"516","ItemName":"Newzeland Lake Tysonno","InRowPlcement":0},
                    {"ItemID":"514","ItemName":"Newzeland Lake Tysonno","InRowPlcement":0},
                    {"ItemID":"546","ItemName":"Underworld Lives","InRowPlcement":0},
                    {"ItemID":"527","ItemName":"In a holiday beach","InRowPlcement":1},
                    {"ItemID":"542","ItemName":"Underworld Lives","InRowPlcement":1},
                    {"ItemID":"525","ItemName":"Lake somewhere","InRowPlcement":1},
                    {"ItemID":"540","ItemName":"Coral Structure at Andaman","InRowPlcement":1},
                    {"ItemID":"569","ItemName":"Ice Rock, Ireland","InRowPlcement":2}
                ];
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="mainModule">
        <div ng-controller="mainCntrl">
            <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in items | groupBy: 'InRowPlcement'">
              <div class="ROW">
                <div class="COLUMN" ng-repeat="item in value">
                    {{ item.ItemName }} 
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Suneet Bansal, the logic looks fine to me but I want to avoid one more external resource to load.